# Regex: Match uint_16 not zero (without negative lookahead)

Tags: regex

I need to match exactly two bytes for anything other than `\x00\x00`.

Is it possible to do it without using negative lookahead? (The Regex engine I use doesn't allow me to)

So as an example:

- `\x00\x00` isn't valid
- `\x30\x31` is valid

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to match exactly two bytes for anything other than `\x00\x00`

You may use this regex with 2 negated characters classes and an alternation:

```sh
^[^\x00]|[^\x00]$
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^\x00]`: Match anything except `\x00`
- `|`: OR
- `[^\x00]`: Match anything except `\x00`
- `$`: End